# Can I recreate content types via db tables only?

Tags: nodes

My D7 (7.18) got corrupted, but just about functioned. However, I couldn't update modules, core or anything, so I took as many backups as I could and did a clean install of 7.24.

I'd like to recreate the custom content types and content I had in the old system (there's a lot). Can I import specific tables into the new MySQL db (from a MySQL export) and expect Drupal to pick it up ok?  If so anyone know which tables I should bring in/merge.

Otherwise anyone got any suggestions for how to recreate content without a few weeks worth of cut+paste?

Thanks
Sparks

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full backup, you could get the old version running locally.

Then

- Content: Migration (http://drupal.org/project/migrate) or Feeds (http://drupal.org/project/feeds)
- Content Types and other code-ish stuff: Features http://drupal.org/project/features

Comment: I only have a windows machine locally, so suspect that may be tricky. But thanks for this - gives me an avenue to investigate. Cheers

Comment: Look at Acquia Dev Desktop or VitrualBox